# A confusion in the proof of $(AB)^T = (B^T A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Let $A = (a_{i,j})_{n\times n}$ and $B = (b_{i,j})_{n\times n}$

$(AB) = (c_{i,j})_{n\times n}$, where $c_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{i,k} b_{k,j}$, so

$(AB)^T = (c_{j,i})$, where  $c_{j,i} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{j,k}b_{k,i} $, and 
$B^T = b_{j,i}$ and $A^T = a_{j,i}$, so

$B^T A^T = d_{j,i}$ where $d_{j,i} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{j,k} a_{k,i}$, but this mean that $(AB)^T \not = (B^T A^T)$, so where is the problem in this derivation ?

Edit: To be clear, lets be more precise;
Let $A = (a_{x,y})_{p\times n}$ and $B = (b_{z,t})_{n\times q}$

So, $A^T_{n\times p} = (a_{y,x})$ and $B^T_{q\times n} = (b_{t,z})$, which implies

$$(B^T A^T)_{i,j}^{q \times p} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{i,k} a_{k,j},$$ and

$(AB)_{c,d}^{p\times q} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{c,k} b_{k,d}$, which implies
$$((AB)^T)_{d,c}^{q\times p} = \sum_{k=1}^n = a_{d,k} b_{k,c}.$$
Since $i,d \in \{1,...,q\}$ and $j,c \in \{1,...,p\}$,
$$((AB)^T)_{d,c}^{q\times p} = \sum_{k=1}^n = a_{d,k} b_{k,c} = = \sum_{k=1}^n = a_{i,k} b_{k,j},$$
which again concludes that $(AB)^T \not = (B^T A^T)$.

Comment: $B^T A^T$ is a matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is given by $$ [B^T A^T]_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} [B^T]_{i,k} [A^T]_{k,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{k,i}a_{j,k}. $$ You must be confused when indexing entries of the transposed matrices.

Comment: @SangchulLee To check that claim, I have made another derivation which I have used different indices for each part.

Comment: You still seem confused. I guess you are understanding that the $(x, y)$-entry of $A^T$ is given by $a_{y,x}$ and likewise for $B^T$. But in the next step you are fooled by the notation again. Since the $(i, k)$-entry of $B^T$ is $b_{k,i}$ and likewise $(k,j)$-entry of $A^T$ is $a_{j,k}$, you should have $$ (B^T A^T)_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{k,i}a_{j,k}. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to know that $(i,j)$-entry of $B^T$ is $b_{j,i}$, that is probably why you are writing $B^T = (b_{j,i})$. The issue is, this notation is confusing as it is not telling you which index denotes the row and which denotes the column. I guess this is where you get confused.

To make things clear, let us use some unconventional notation: A matrix $A$ whose $(i,j)$-entry is $a_{i,j}$ is denoted by the following function notation

$$A = [(i,j)\mapsto a_{i,j}].$$

So if you know that $A$ is given by $A = [\text{some function of the pair }(i, j)]$, then you simply evaluate that function at $(i,j)$ to retrieve its $(i,j)$-entry. This seemingly stupid tautology is in fact helping because the transpose of $A$ is written by $A^T = [(i,j) \mapsto a_{j,i}]$, where the role of $i$ and $j$ are now explicit. Then

\begin{align*}
\text{$(i,j)$-entry of $B^TA^T$}
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\text{$(i,k)$-entry of $B^T$})\cdot(\text{$(k,j)$-entry of $A^T$}) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\text{value of $(x, y)\mapsto b_{y,x}$ at $(x,y) = (i,k)$}) \\
&\hspace{3em} \cdot(\text{value of $(z, t)\mapsto a_{t,z}$ at $(z,t) = (k,j)$}) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{k,i} a_{j,k}
 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{j,k}b_{k,i}
 = \text{$(j,i)$-entry of $AB$}.
\end{align*}

---

If it is still not convincing, it never hurts to consider a concrete example. Consider

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \end{pmatrix}, \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} \\ b_{31} & b_{32} \end{pmatrix} $$

Then $[AB]_{11} = a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31}$ as expected. Now consider their transpose:

$$ A^{T} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{21} \\ a_{12} & a_{22} \\ a_{13} & a_{23} \end{pmatrix}, \qquad B^{T} = \begin{pmatrix} b_{11} & b_{21} & b_{31} \\ b_{12} & b_{22} & b_{32} \end{pmatrix}. $$

Now the $(1,2)$-entry of the product $B^T A^T$ is given by

\begin{align*}
[B^T A^T]_{12}
&= [B^T]_{11}[A^T]_{12} + [B^T]_{12}[A^T]_{22} + [B^T]_{13}[A^T]_{32} \\
&= b_{11}a_{21} + b_{21}a_{22} + b_{31}a_{23} \\
&= a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21} + a_{23}b_{31} \\
&= [AB]_{21}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

OK, your notations confusing. It's very hard to understand what you mean by $(c_{j,i})$, so let's start over.

---

Let's call $AB = C$, and let's call $B^TA^T=D$. What we want to prove is $C^T=D$.

First of all, let's say that the element in $C$'s $i$-th row and $j$-th column is $c_{ij}$. Then you know that $$c_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}.$$

Now, let's say that the element in $D$'s $i$-th row and $j$-th column is $d_{ij}$. Then we know that $$d_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n b'_{ik}a'_{kj}$$

Where $a'_{ik}$ is the element of $A^T$ and $b'_{kj}$ of $B^T$.

Next, since that's what transposition is, we know that $a'_{ik} = a_{ki}$ which means that $$d_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{ki}a_{jk}$$

---

Now you have to show that $d_{ij} = c_{ji}$ for all $i,j$. Since you know what $c_{ij}$ is equal to, you know that $c_{ji}$ is equal (if you replace every $i$ with $j$ and every $j$ with $i$) to

$$c_{ji} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{jk}b_{ki}$$
which is exactly the same as $d_{ij}$ and you are done.

---

If you don't like the fact that we switch $i$ and $j$, you can also introduce new variables to make it more clear:

We want to prove that $C^T=D$ which means we want to prove that $c_{qp} = d_{pq}$ for all $q,p$ (I am using different indices to avoid confusion). Since we know what $c_{ij}$ is *for any value $i,j$*, we can now substitute $i=p$ and $j=q$ to get

$$c_{qp} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{qk} b_{kp}$$

and

$$d_{pq} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{kp} a_{qk}.$$

Now it's easy to see that $c_{qp}=d_{pq}$.

---

**AFTER EDIT**:

---

After your edit, the mistake comes in the line

> $$(B^T A^T)_{i,j}^{q \times p} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{i,k} a_{k,j}$$

because that is not true. In fact, $$\sum_{k=1}^n b_{i,k} a_{k,j}$$ is equal to $$(BA)_{i,j}.$$

Since you want $(B^TA^T)_{i,j}$, you want

$$(B^T A^T)_{i,j}^{q \times p} = \sum_{k=1}^n b'_{i,k} a'_{k,j}$$

where $b'_{i,k} = (B^T)_{i,k}$ and $a'_{i,k} = (A^T)_{k,j}$.

Then, you use the fact that $$b'_{i,k} = b_{k,i}$$ to get the correct result, which is

$$(B^T A^T)_{i,j}^{q \times p} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{k,i} a_{j,k}$$

Comment: See my edit, I have add another similar derivation.

Comment: I have checked your your method, but still can't see where is the problem in my derivation.

Comment: @Leth The problem is in your calculation of $(B^TA^T)_{ij}$. What you wrote down is $(BA)_{ij}$. You forgot to transpose $B$ and $A$..

Comment: No actually, $i \in 1,...,q$, so I don't see any problem.

Comment: @Leth Well there is a problem. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Leth $i\in 1,\dots, q$ doesn't help you with the fact that $b_{ik} \neq b_{ki}$.

Comment: But with this conclusion, $(B^T A^T)_{i,j}^{q \times p} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{k,i} a_{j,k}$ in the RHS, $i \in 1,...,q$, and in the LHS, $i\in 1,..,n$ since the second index of the $b$ is in $1,...,n$

Comment: @Leth Where in the lhs is $i\in 1,\dots, n$?

Comment: @Leth LHS: $$(B^TA^T)_{i,j}^{q\times p} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{k,i} a_{j,k}$$ which means that $i$ goes from $1$ to $q$, because we are taking $b_{k,i}$ and $B$ only has $q$ columns.

Comment: Ok, while I was writing an explanation, I realised that indeed in LHS $i \in 1,...,q $

Comment: @Leth Great, so everything is clear now?

Comment: In a couple of minutes, I hope :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59982/discussion-between-5xum-and-leth).

Answer (score 2):

Why are you making things so difficult?

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix, $B$ be a $n \times p$ matrix.

$$(B^TA^T)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(B^{T})_{ik}(A^T)_{kj}$$

$$= \sum_{k=1}^{n}B_{ki}A_{jk}$$
$$= \sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{jk}B_{ki}$$
$$=(AB)_{ji}$$
$$=((AB)^{T})_{ij}$$

Therefore we conclude

$$(AB)^T = B^T A^T$$

Comment: Because I'm sociopath, duhh ?

Comment: Apart from the joke, if I cannot figure out the mistake in my derivation, I will came across the same problem again in the future.I mean like if I try to prove the same thing one month later, I will again use my same method, so it is better to figure out my own mistake then just accept another's derivation.

Comment: It is, and trust me on this one, sometimes preferable to look into an elegant proof, although it may be harder for you to understand. If someone told you that it doesn't matter how you prove something, if it is correct, they are wrong.

Comment: What you say it a generalisation, and they are always wrong except than this one, so I will trust you on that :)

Answer (score 1):

In the world of real vector spaces, one can define $A^T$ to be the adjoint of $A$ with respect to the Euclidean inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ (this adjoint is unique). More precisely, $A^T$ is the unique linear mapping so that $$\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^Ty\rangle \qquad \forall x,y$$ 
Similarly, $B^T$ and $(AB)^T$ are the unique linear mappings so that
$$\langle Bx,y\rangle = \langle x,B^Ty\rangle \qquad \forall x,y$$ 
and
$$\langle (AB)x,y\rangle = \langle x,(AB)^Ty\rangle \qquad \forall x,y.$$
Now, note that
$$ \langle (AB)x,y\rangle=\langle A(Bx),y\rangle=\langle Bx,A^Ty\rangle=\langle x,B^TA^Ty\rangle=\langle x,(B^TA^T)y\rangle$$
By uniqueness of the adjoint, we directly obtain $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$. Note that the advantage of this proof is that it holds for the adjoint operator of matrices defined with respect to any inner product. Doing the same for complex vector spaces, we obtain that $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$ where $A^*$ is the Hermitian conjugate of $A$.

**Note:** To obtain uniqueness of the adjoint, simply plug in all the pairs of vectors taken from an orthogonal basis for $x,y$ in the above equations.